# show that two roots of $a(x^2)-(a^2)x-x+a=0$ are reciprocals of each other

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials

I wanted to ask how can I find the reciprocals of the roots of this equation? What I tried was factorizing it however, the teacher was not satisfied with the answers even though I got $x=1/a$ and $a=1/x$

$a(x^2)-(a^2)x-x+a=0$

Comment: You get $x = a$ and $x = 1/a$ after factoring $$ax^{2} - a^{2}x - x + a = 0 \implies ax(x-a) -1(x-a) = 0 \implies (ax-1)(x-a) = 0$$ which are reciprocals.

Comment: "the teacher was not satisfied with the answers even though I got x=1/a and a=1/x" A possibility is that they would have preferred to read: $x=a$ and $x=1/a$. Dunno...

Comment: Notice that $x=\frac1a$ is equivalent with $a=\frac1x$ so you've found only one root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$ax^2-(a^2)x-x+a=0\to ax(x-a)-(x-a)=0$$

$$(x-a)(ax-1)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\alpha$ solves the equation. Then $a\alpha^2-a^2\alpha-\alpha+a=0$. Hence,
$$\alpha a(\alpha-a)-(\alpha-a)=0\\(\alpha a-1)(\alpha-a)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Iа $x_1, x_2$ are roots of the equation then by Vieta theorem we have that their product equals 1, so $x_1 x_2=1$   and $x_1=\frac{1}{x_2}.$